# Use PHP variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, dynamic

I've been searching for a working solution for a couple of days now, but I just can't get it to work.

I've the following code in my `test.php`

```
<?php
    $testNumber = 2;
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js";
$(function) {
    func(<?php echo json_encode($testNumber); ?>);
});
</script>
```

And the following code in my test.js

```
function func(testNumber) {
    if (testNumber > 1){
        alert("function works );
    } else {
        alert("Function does NOT work");
    }
}

func();
```

When I run `test.php`, I get the alert `"Function does NOT work".` 
While `$testNumber` is greater then 1.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That is not even valid JS. In fact, that does not even render valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

As always, you should look at the source that is sent to the browser - what your PHP looks like doesn't matter when determining why something doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js";
$(function) {
    func(2);
});
</script>
```

This is NOT valid HTML, because you should have `>` instead of `;` on that first line, and you can't have a `<script>` tag that is both internal and external.

Additionally, `$(function) { func(2); });` isn't even valid JavaScript, but that's not too big of an issue because it's never parsed as JS, just as a weird set of attributes on your broken `<script>` element.

Now, as for why your script doesn't work, you are calling `func()` with no parameter, therefore `testNumber` is `undefined` (as you would see if you tried `alert(testNumber)`), therefore it is not greater than 1, therefore "Function does NOT work".

Answer (score 0):

change it to :

```
<?php
$testNumber = 2;
?>

<script type="text/javascript" >;    
    function func(testNumber) {
        if (testNumber > 1){
            alert("Function works");
        } else {
            alert("Function does NOT work");
        }
    }
    func(<?php echo $testNumber; ?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<?php
    $testNumber = 2;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function func(testNumber) {
    if (testNumber > 1){
        alert("function works ");
    } else {
        alert("Function1 does NOT work");
    }
}


 func(<?php echo json_encode($testNumber); ?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $testNumber = 2; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    func(<?php echo $testNumber; ?>);

    function func(testNumber) {
        if (testNumber > 1){
            alert("function works );
        } else {
            alert("Function does NOT work");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is because while you `json_encode` the variable is no longer a number

Try this instead:

```
        func(<?php echo (int)$testnumber; ?>);
```

Comment: Agree with you @h2ooooooo

Comment: `json_encode(2)` gives the string `"2"`, but when you output a string it doesn't get quotes around it ;) So result is `func(2)`, as it should be. That part of the code is 100% correct.